# quill: update target attribute when editing link

Tags: javascript, npm, quill

I am a Japanese web developer beginner.
I am not good at English, sorry.

I customized quill to select the target attribute when inserting a link.

--snow.js--

```
SnowTooltip.TEMPLATE = [
  '<a class="ql-preview" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="about:blank" target="_blank"></a>',
  '<input type="text" data-formula="e=mc^2" data-link="https://quilljs.com" data-video="Embed URL">',
  '<a class="ql-action" id="link-self"></a>',
  '<a class="ql-action" id="link-blank"></a>',
  '<a class="ql-remove"></a>',
].join('');
```

I edited the html of the tooltip.

I made these two buttons:

```
'<a class="ql-action" id="link-self"></a>',
'<a class="ql-action" id="link-blank"></a>',
```

---

And then,

```
this.root.querySelector('a#link-self').addEventListener('click', event => {
      process.env.NODE_LINK_TARGET = '_self';
      if (this.root.classList.contains('ql-editing')) {
        this.save();
      } else {
        this.edit('link', this.preview.textContent);
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    });
    this.root.querySelector('a#link-blank').addEventListener('click', event => {
      process.env.NODE_LINK_TARGET = '_blank';
      if (this.root.classList.contains('ql-editing')) {
        this.save();
      } else {
        this.edit('link', this.preview.textContent);
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

I edited listen function.

process.env.NODE_LINK_TARGET = '_self';

I added the target attribute string on `process.env`.

--link.js--

```
static create(value) {
    const node = super.create(value);
    node.setAttribute('href', this.sanitize(value));
    node.setAttribute('target', process.env.NODE_LINK_TARGET);
    return node;
  }
```

I edited the create function in the link.js file to set the target attribute.

When you create a new link you can select the target attribute from two buttons.

```
'<a class="ql-action" id="link-self"></a>'
'<a class="ql-action" id="link-blank"></a>'
```

But when you edit the link and save by pushing these buttons, the target attribute doesn't change.

I want to update not only the href attribute of the link but also the target attribute.

Is there any solution?

Please please help me.

(T___T)

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work:

```js
    // BEGIN add target="_blank" to images
    const BaseLink = Quill.import("formats/link");
    class Link extends BaseLink {
      format(name, value) {
        if (["href", "target"].indexOf(name) > -1) {
          if (value) {
            this.domNode.setAttribute(name, value);
          } else {
            this.domNode.removeAttribute(name);
          }
        } else {
          super.format(name, value);
        }
      }
      static create(value) {
        const node = super.create(value);
        node.setAttribute("href", this.sanitize(value));
        node.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        return node;
      }
    }
    Quill.register(Link, true);
    // END add target="_blank" to images
    enter code here
```